# Using two or more SecurityFilterChains with Spring Security 6 does not work properly, only one chain is invoked

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-6

I have trouble to get my two `SecurityFilterhain`s work in conjunction with each other using Spring Security 6.
For one of my endpoint paths (`/v1/transactions/**`) I want the user to authorize with Oauth2 and for the other endpoint path (`/v1/info`) Basic Auth is required. Only one of the configurations works as expected depending on which `@Order()` they have.

With the below two `SecurityFilterChain` configurations I am able to make requests to `/v1/info` using Basic Auth but not making requests to `/v1/transaction/**` using Oauth2 which just gives me 401 Access Denied.

If I change the order so `basicAuthSecurityFilterChain` gets `@Order(2)` and `oauth2SecurityFilterChain` gets `@Order(1)` then I can make calls to `/v1/transaction/**` using OAauth2 but not make calls to `/v1/info` using Basic Auth which then gives me 401 Access Denied.

I am not sure why I encounter this behaviour since the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.4.0/reference/html5/#servlet-securityfilterchain) tells me that the invocation of a SecurityFilterChain is decided based on the path and the paths for the basic auth and oauth2 resources are different (`/v1/transaction/**` vs `/v1/info`).

```java
@EnableMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class BasicAuthSecurity {
    
    public AuthenticationManager authProviderManager() { //omitted code) }

    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    public SecurityFilterChain basicAuthSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .authenticationManager(authProviderManager())
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers(POST, "/v1/info", "/v1/info/{user}").hasRole("user")
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .httpBasic(withDefaults())
                .build();
    }
}
```

And for the OAuth2 SecurityFilterChain I am using this:

```java
@EnableMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class Oauth2Security {

    @Bean
    @Order(2)
    public SecurityFilterChain oauth2SecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers(POST, "/v1/transaction/**")
                        .hasAnyRole("poweruser", "admin")
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .oauth2ResourceServer()
                .jwt()
                .and().and().build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

you are missing `securityMatcher` in the first filter-chain in `@Order`. That simple :/

```java
    // Applies only to the specified security-matchers
    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    public SecurityFilterChain basicAuthSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.securityMatcher("/v1/info/**");
        return http
                .authenticationManager(authProviderManager())
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers(POST, "/v1/info", "/v1/info/{user}").hasRole("user")
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .httpBasic(withDefaults())
                .build();
    }
    
    // this one has lowest precedence (higher order) and no security matcher 
    // => behaves as default when higher precedence (lower order) ones security matchers did not match 
    @Bean
    @Order(2)
    public SecurityFilterChain oauth2SecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers(POST, "/v1/transaction/**")
                        .hasAnyRole("poweruser", "admin")
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .oauth2ResourceServer()
                .jwt()
                .and().and().build();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you!! It solved it. Strange that the docs does not mention the `securityMatcher` in chapter 9.4 but first in chapter 16.3.

Comment: Follow up-question: let us say both `SecurityFilterChain`s contain a request matcher for `/v1/global-resource/**`. I thought `http.securityMatchers(matcher -> matcher.requestMatchers(request -> request.getHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION).startsWith("Basic")));` in the `basicAuthSecurityFilterChain` would be enough but apparently it is not since I never reach the `oauth2SecurityFilterChain` when requesting `/v1/global-resource/info` using OAuth2 authorization. Is it not the correct way to handle this situation?

Comment: Only one security filter chain is evaluated and it is the security matchers which determine which one. Your security matchers must be precise enough to catch only the request to be processed by the filter-chain it belong to.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I see. But according to my example in the follow-up question the Oauth2 requests should always get into the `oauth2SecurityFilterChain` filter chain since the `Authorization` header always starts with `Bearer` for Aauth2 requests. And for Basic auth requests it should always lead me into the `basicAuthSecurityFilterChain` since the `Authorization` header of basic auth requests always start with `Basic`. I guess I can filter on other things such as headers and not only URLs and path:es? Right?

Comment: I had overlooked your preceding comment and missed the matcher on the header, sorry. This matcher definitively needs some null safety (what if the authorization header is missing?), but apart from that, I don't know why it doesn't work as you expect (sorry for that too).

Comment: Yeah, I have omitted null checks and other checks just to spare characters. So we can for simplicity assume that NPE:s never occur in the code examples above. :-) 
Anyway, thanks for your help. I will dive into the docs and try figuring out what I have missed.

Comment: You did save my day. Thanks for the solutions. Cheers!