# Disable logout redirect and call custom logout rest end point in springboot 3

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I am working on a springboot 3 application. I had to work with Jwt object so I had to import this dependency along with `spring-boot-starter-security`

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

I had a custom `/logout` rest endpoint.
Now with this new dependency when I call my endpoint, it returns a `302` code and redirects to `/login?logout`.

So I changed my configuration as below to make it call custom rest endpoint, however it only returns a `302` with redirect URL.

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .authorizeHttpRequests(request -> request
                    .requestMatchers("/login*")
                            .permitAll()
                            .anyRequest()
                            .permitAll())
            .logout(logout -> logout.logoutSuccessUrl("/cms/logout").permitAll());
    http.httpBasic(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);
    return http.build();
}
```

I don't want it to redirect to another URL, I just want to call my custom logout rest endpoint.

I tried the below approach, but its not working

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .authorizeHttpRequests(request -> request
                    .requestMatchers("/login*")
                            .permitAll()
                            .anyRequest()
                            .permitAll())
            .logout(logout -> logout.permitAll()
            .logoutSuccessHandler(((request, response, authentication) -> new CustomLogoutHandler())));
    http.httpBasic(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);
    return http.build();
}


private class CustomLogoutHandler implements LogoutSuccessHandler{
    @Autowired
    AuthServiceImpl authService;
    @Override
    public void onLogoutSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        authService.cmslogout(request,response);
    }
}
```

If I remove the logout then this what I see in the browser:
[image]
It would be even better if this spring-security logout handling can be disabled as a whole.

I have defined the `SecurityFilterChain` bean because we already have custom authentication in place for this resource server. The access tokens are passed in cookies for the custom authentication. But now, I need to support the keycloak OIDC. In this case I get access token as part of the `Authorization` header. I have specific filter for this which intercepts the requests and decides the authentication flow.

For keycloak OIDC my angular frontend app acts a `client-server` and is responsible to get the access tokens from keylcloak and add it to any API calls to the `resource-server`.

With this `SecurityFilterChain` configuration I'm permitting all the requests and it avoids the `spring-security'`s default login form.
Now I need to bypass the logout redirection as well.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

> It would be even better if this spring-security logout handling can be disabled as a whole.

Just provide nothing about logout (no handler, no success-handler, no endpoint, nothing).

Neither login nor logout make sense on an OAuth2 **resource server**. This are OAuth2 **client** concerns. See the [OAuth2 essentials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials#oauth_essentials) section of my tutorials.

Also, see inside the [resource server tutorial](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/blob/master/samples/tutorials/servlet-resource-server/src/main/java/com/c4soft/springaddons/tutorials/WebSecurityConfig.java) to return proper `401` to unauthorized requests (instead of `302` *redirect to login*):

```java
http.exceptionHandling(eh -> eh.authenticationEntryPoint((request, response, authException) -> {
    response.addHeader(HttpHeaders.WWW_AUTHENTICATE, "Bearer realm=\"Restricted Content\"");
    response.sendError(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value(), HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.getReasonPhrase());
}));
```

Comment: So you want me to remove the securityfilterChain bean?

Comment: This is a question you would not ask if you had followed the links.

Comment: from what I understand, the resource server must reject any request that does not have the `Bearer` token. In my case, the configuration that I have posted in the question is needed because I have to support two types of authentication. I have updated the question with my use case. Please help.

Comment: You should read the tutorials I linked. Your Angular app should not be an OAuth2 client and it should not have access to tokens. According to latest recommendations, only applications on your servers can be reliable OAuth2 clients.

Comment: When you want more than one mechanism to authorize requests, you define one `SecurityFilterChain` for each, as answered for instance [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75874384/619830)

Comment: To return to the question (logout) , read the answer again: the resource server should not be involved

Comment: Ok, I can make my spring cloud gateway as a client server, but this oidc authentication is just optional, my original custom authentication should work. How can I achieve that?

Comment: With two distinct `SecurityFilterChain` beans (as already explained) .