# Redirect to OAuth2 login page in Spring MVC with Spring Security 6

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-thymeleaf, spring-security-6

I have an Spring MVC jsf application. Each page/endpoint requests are secured with `customAuthorizationManager`.

I'm trying to redirect any unauthenticated/unauthorized request to our OAuth2 server's login page (**https://xxx/op/v1/auth**).

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    .....

    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain1(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorizeRequests ->
                        authorizeRequests.anyRequest().access(customAuthorizationManager)
                )
                // Redirect to the OAuth 2.0 Login endpoint when not authenticated from the authorization endpoint
                .exceptionHandling(exceptions -> exceptions
                        .defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(
                                new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("https://xxx/op/v1/auth"),
                                new MediaTypeRequestMatcher(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
                        )
                );

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(2)
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain2(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                // OAuth2 Login handles the redirect to the OAuth 2.0 Login endpoint from the authorization server filter chain above
                .oauth2Login(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .oauth2Client(c -> this.customClientRegistration());

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository() {
        return new InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository(this.customClientRegistration());
    }

    private ClientRegistration customClientRegistration() {
        return ClientRegistration
                .withRegistrationId("my-combined-client")
                .clientId("4d06125e-xxx")
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
                .redirectUri("https://xxx")
                .authorizationUri("https://xxx/op/v1/auth")
                .tokenUri("https://xxx/op/v1/token")
                .userInfoUri("https://xxx/op/v1/userinfo")
                .jwkSetUri("https://xxx/op/v1/keys")
                .build();
    }

}
```

I see that an unauthorized request is rejected and redirected to the login page fine but not with the right **client-id** as defined in `customClientRegistration` (**4d06125e-xxx**)

[image: request1]

[image: request2]

So, could you please help me with the redirection of these unauthenticated/unauthorized requests to the external OAuth login page?

---

**UPDATE 1** @ch4mp 's comment

I've removed the second filter and append his content into the first but the result is the same:

```
@Bean
@Order(1)
public SecurityFilterChain filter1(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authorizeRequests ->
                    authorizeRequests.anyRequest().access(customAuthorizationManager)
            )
            // Redirect to the OAuth 2.0 Login endpoint when not authenticated from the authorization endpoint
            .exceptionHandling(exceptions -> exceptions
                    .defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(
                            new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("https://xxx/op/v1/auth"),
                            new MediaTypeRequestMatcher(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
                    )
            )
            .oauth2Login(Customizer.withDefaults())
            .oauth2Client(c -> this.customClientRegistration());

    return http.build();
}

/*@Bean
@Order(2)
public SecurityFilterChain filter2(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            // OAuth2 Login handles the redirect to the OAuth 2.0 Login endpoint from the authorization server filter chain above
            .oauth2Login(Customizer.withDefaults())
            .oauth2Client(c -> this.customClientRegistration());

    return http.build();
}*/
```

---

**UPDATE 2** @ch4mp 's answer

```
@Bean
@Order(1)
public SecurityFilterChain filter1(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authorizeRequests ->
                    authorizeRequests.anyRequest().access(customAuthorizationManager)
            )
            // Redirect to the OAuth 2.0 Login endpoint when not authenticated from the authorization endpoint
            /*.exceptionHandling(exceptions -> exceptions
                    .defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(
                            new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("https://xxx/op/v1/auth"),
                            new MediaTypeRequestMatcher(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
                    )
            )*/
            .oauth2Login(Customizer.withDefaults())
            .oauth2Client(c -> this.customClientRegistration());

    return http.build();
}
```

I've removed the `.exceptionHandling` . It does a request to `https://myAppPath/oauth2/authorization/my-combined-client` instead of to the server defined in the client `https://xxx/op/v1/auth`. So 404.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using two or more SecurityFilterChains with Spring Security 6 does not work properly, only one chain is invoked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75874011/using-two-or-more-securityfilterchains-with-spring-security-6-does-not-work-prop)

Comment: @ch4mp I've moved the `filter2` into `filter1` as you can see in my post update. The result is the same:( I assume that the `customClientRegistration` is not used during the `LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint`process.

Answer (score 1):

Remove your `exceptionHandling`.

The first request in an authorization-code flow is to the OAuth2 client for it to setup the session, nonce, state, etc. The OAuth2 client will redirect the user to the authorization server "authorization" endpoint and wait until he comes back with an authorization-code.

Comment: I've removed that `exceptionHandling`. But now I get an 404 because it does a request to `https://myAppPath/oauth2/authorization/my-combined-client` instead of to external OAuth server `https://xxx/op/v1/auth`

Comment: This `/oauth2/authorization/{registration-id}` endpoint should be auto-generated by Spring (as well as `/login/oauth2/code/{registration-id}`). It could be worth to check Spring Security DEBUG logs to figure out why it isn't.

Comment: May be there is a little bit different implementation is needed since it is an mvc jsf application?

Comment: Here is a [Spring OAuth2 client with Thymeleaf](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/resource-server_with_ui) (not a JSF app, but still server-side rendered UI). Unless you provide with your debug logs, all I can do is to direct you there...